# Netty 4 - ByteToMessageDecoder with multi-byte delimiter

Tags: netty

In my Netty 3.x FrameDecoder implementation I make use of the ChannelBufferIndexFinder to help me find the delimiter between FIX (http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org) messages.  The delimiter is defined as a series of characters.  To find the delimiter, I am utilising the ChannelBuffer.indexOf() method with my implementation of the ChannelBufferIndexFinder.

The ChannelBufferIndexFinder passes in the ChannelBuffer, so I was able to check other bytes in the buffer for the delimiter.

With Netty 4.x, the ByteBuf.indexOf() only allows me to search for a single byte.  Alternatively, there is also ByteBuf.forEachByte(ByteBufProcessor), however a ByteBufProcessor once again only gives me access to a single byte.

Is there a way to find my delimiter?  I'm guessing at the moment my only solution will be to roll my own equivalent version of ByteBuf.forEachByte() that spans multiple bytes?  Something like what the DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder.indexOf() has done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use `io.netty.handler.codec.DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder` with a `io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf` containing the series of characters.

**DEPRECATED**

You may use your own implementation of `io.netty.buffer.ByteBufIndexFinder` with something similar to

```
@Override
public boolean find(final ByteBuf buffer, final int index) {
    boolean found;

    if (validateIndex(buffer, index)
            && sufficentBytesReadable(buffer, index)) {
        final byte byte0 = buffer.getByte(index);
        final byte byte1 = buffer.getByte(index + 1);
        found = byte0 == '\r' && byte1 == '\n';
    } else {
        found = false;
    }

    return found;
}
private boolean sufficentBytesReadable(final ByteBuf buffer,
        final int index) {
    return buffer.writerIndex() - index >= 2;
}
private boolean validateIndex(final ByteBuf buffer, final int index) {
    return index >= buffer.readerIndex() && index <= buffer.writerIndex();
}
```

Comment: From what I understand, the ByteBufIndexFinder has been removed.  https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1532

Comment: I'm sorry. I used it in a pre-final version last time.